# How to compile dependent library projects in Intellij IDEA

Tags: build, intellij-idea

I have two projects. Project A is my general utility library that is updated A LOT (at least few times a day). Project B is application I currently work on. Project B imports Project A as library. Can I force IntelliJ IDEA to compile Project A (ideally only when it's needed, i.e. Project A has been modified) during compilation of Project B? I don't want to build Project A by hand each time I fix bug in my library as it's inconvenient and error prone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the [module dependencies](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html). Everything will be compiled incrementally and automatically when you make any change, either in a library or in the client code.

Comment: I managed to make it work, but I'm not sure if I did it the right way. I opened Project B Settings->Modules->Sources->Add Content Root and selected Project A directory. Then Project B compiled. However when I create global library out of Project A and add it to Project B->Settings->Modules->Dependencies it(Project A) is not compiled. Is it expected behavior? The doc You linked to suggests that adding library should be enough (Note: adding Project A to Project B dependencies through Project B->Settings->Modules->Dependencies->Add->Jars or directories also does not seem to work).

Comment: You should add **Module** dependency, not jar, not directory.